# section header is always alligned to same x position

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I ma using CGRectMake in my code but it is not affecting the following code

```
    - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if(section==1){

    UILabel *v=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 150, 10)];
    [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [v setText:@"Apartments that matches your search ..."];
    [v setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [v setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f]];

    return v;

}
return NULL;
}
```

I want UILabel at the center of TableView , please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 UILabel *v=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 10)];
[v setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
```

Answer (score 1):

Any view you return from this method is automatically scaled and positioned to fill the width of the screen. Set the `textAlignment` of the label to centered to get the effect you want.